# import flat file SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a table destination SQL Server that is load from flat file that would be fixed width. 
The destination table has 5 fields but some rows of flat file have 3 information and in the final of row there is row delimiter and the process go to next row to load the others 2 fields. 
The result in the table doesn't satisfy.

Adding information, I am using SSIS in Visual Studio 2015 and the component is Flat File Source

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If the data source is malformed, it cannot be loaded. The best answer would be for the data source to produce a file that conforms to the file format requirements. If that is not possible, it might be easy enough to "patch up" with a PowerShell script.

Comment: As @lit mentioned, ensure that format of your source data it's well-formed (in case for a `csv` file, for example, ensure the delimiter it's used properly). Also, if there's a field missing for any row on the source data, replace with `NULL`. This can be done by using **Transformation task**.